# Nominatim Autocomplete Widget (Geocoding)

Tags: android, geocoding, nominatim

An autocomplete widget is "a search dialog with built-in autocomplete functionality. As a user enters search terms, the widget presents a list of predicted places to choose from. When the user makes a selection, a Place instance is returned, which your app can then use to get details about the selected place." (Google Maps Android)

My question: **Is there an Autocomplete widget for Android Studio that is compatible with Nominatim?**

If not, is there a **simple** and **light** Java API for Nominatim to be used in Android Studio?

Comment: https://github.com/antoinesauray/nominatim-android